# Do we need locking if we are appending and reading data from vector simultaneously?(no-modification)

Tags: c++, vector, append, locking, push

We know that if more than one thread operates on an object and there is a modification involved, we need some kind of locking(atomic/mutex). For my case only these operations are happening simultaneously for a std::vector:

```
1. Read
2. Append/Push
```

Will the vector need a lock in this case? and if yes, why? My program is based on CPP.

I'm new to the lock concept. Any hint in the right direction will work for me.

Comment: When you append, it may happen that a reallocation is needed.

Comment: When appending (push_back) you will need full locking blocking reads, writes,  and appends as the internal storage of the vector may be re-allocated.  If you can pre-allocate the vector and don't share array elements between threads then no locking is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need locking, in general, because `push_back` can cause reallocation.

You can check the reference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back says

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and
> references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated.
> Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/ mentions:

> The container is modified. If a reallocation happens, all contained
> elements are modified. Otherwise, no existing element is accessed, and
> concurrently accessing or modifying them is safe.

So, you should lock if you want to be careful. Or if you care about clean maintainable code.

If you need extra performance and know what you are doing, you can get away with locking only when you know that no `push_back()` will bring `size()` above `capacity()`. That is very tricky and error prone: as soon as you allow one thread to start reading, you have to be sure no reallocation will occur in other thread, even later.

Edit: re-worded above. tl-dr: use synchronization :-)

Comment: _you can get away with locking only when_ No, because one (or more) threads can be in the middle of a read access when the writer thread locks and reallocates (i.e., the read threads are already past the lock when the writer acquires it). You could try to get fancy and have the writer wait until there are no active readers but even then there are subtle issues to consider.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm On high-performance system, one could go with a semaphore, allow multiple concurrent readers, and force the readers out before pushing_back to reallocate. But yeah, probably way more advanced than what OP needs. (thanks for pointing out the error in original answer)

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely need resource locking. Take this example, if you insert an element to the vector, it might resize. Now when your resizing the vector, what if another thread tries to access data from the array. See a clash? That's why need to lock resources. Now this is if your inserting or removing data (meaning that your altering the actual allocation of the container). If the size is fixed (meaning if you have pre-allocated it), then there wont be an issue.